# jQuery dialog file upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-file-upload

Im trying to upload a file and some strings from a jQuery dialog window to my php site.
I used ajax to send the string data but now i read that i cant upload files with ajax. What is the best solution to get this work ?

The HTML:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Quelle hinzufügen">
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <form id= "file-form" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                Datei zum Hochladen auswählen:
                <input type="file" name="file-sel" id="file-select"/>
            </form>
        <tr>    
        <tr>
            <p> Nicht bekannte Felder bitte leer lassen. </br></p>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Titel</td>
            <td>Person(en)</td>
            <td>Jahr</td>   
            <td>Schlagworte</td>    
            <td>Veröffentlicht in</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="titelin" id="titelin" value="" class="text ui-widget content ui corner-all"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="personin" id="personin" value="" class="text ui-widget content ui corner-all"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="jahrin" id="jahrin" value="" class="text ui-widget content ui corner-all"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="tagsin" id="tagsin" value="" class="text ui-widget content ui corner-all"></td>    
            <td><input type="text" name="verin" id="verin" value="" class="text ui-widget content ui corner-all"></td>                  
</form>
```

Script :

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false ,
        width: 1500,
        buttons: {
            "Quelle hinzufügen": function() {
                var out = [];
                out.push(document.getElementById("titelin").value);
                out.push(document.getElementById("personin").value);
                out.push(document.getElementById("jahrin").value);  
                out.push(document.getElementById("tagsin").value);  
                out.push(document.getElementById("verin").value);   
                ajax(out);                       
        },   
        Abbrechen: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }   
    }   
}); 

function ajax(info){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"quellenverzeichnis.php",
        data: {output: info},                
        success: function(data){
            alert("Quelle wurde hinzugefügt");                  
        },
        error:  function(){
            alert("fail");
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: ' but now i read that i cant upload files with ajax.'-  You can upload file using Ajax.

Comment: ok so I'am wrong, but how is it done ?

Comment: You can submit a form using ajax. For example,

var formData = new FormData('form Id');
    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your url',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
 
    });

Comment: Your solution produces an error for me :" Uncaught Typeerror: illegal invocation" with the reference to jquery file in line 9503

Comment: I have just give you a one example of ajax function for form submit.
For proper code just search how to submit a form using ajax function. you will find code easily.